# TRUMP to BIDEN : This transition won't be easy

Tags: wordplay, no-computers, humor, word-ladder

> Can you change the word TRUMP to the name BIDEN in 10 steps or less by
> changing one letter at a time?

Each change must result in a valid word from MW dictionary.

No proper nouns, abbreviations or acronyms. No rearrangement or anagrams either.

Have fun.

I did it in 10 but there must be a faster solution??

Comment: I can change it in one step... VOTE :) My initial run was 12 steps, but I'm sure I can tweak it down a bit lower.

Comment: "No proper nouns". Well, Biden is a proper noun (Trump is not; e.g. we can have trumps when playing card games like whist and bridge).

Comment: What transition? :P

Comment: Nice puzzle, definitely worthy of the humour tag

Comment: If letters can be added and removed, I can do it in 7 steps.

Comment: Is HIDEN a word?

Comment: @Richard No not in MW dictionary. HIDED is.

Comment: @AnthonyIngram-Westover you can not, but we can!  Together, we will!

Comment: @trolley813 - in the North of England, a 'trump' is a fart. In standard English, it is a blast on a trumpet (there is predicted to be a 'last trump', at the end of the world, in the Bible).

Comment: "TRUMP->TRAMP->GRAMP->GRAME->GRACE->GLACE->PLACE->PEACE->PENCE" would also be an alternative, after "COVID->COMID->COMPD->COMPS->COOPS->CROPS->CRAPS->CRAMS->CRAMP->CRUMP->TRUMP->GRUMP->GRAMP->GRAME->GRAVE".

Comment: Do you know how to obtain a wordlist from the  MW dictionary? I wasn't able to find one had to use `aspell`, but `MW` is probably more complete, so there may be smaller paths in that DB.

Comment: @user000001: I used https://github.com/dwyl/english-words and couldn't find anything better than the accepted solution.

Comment: I found a solution with 7 steps, using terms defined in https://www.urbandictionary.com/. There are some proper nouns (first names), though.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Based on ThatOneNerdyBoy's answer, here's a 9-step solution in which all words are contained within MW

> TRUMP
>  TRAMP
>  TRAMS
>  TEAMS
>  TERMS
>  [TERES](https://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/teres)
>  TIRES
>  TIDES
>  BIDES
>  BIDEN

Comment: That looks better!

Comment: @Lukas Rotter  I am going to wait a couple of days before I accept your answer. Still hope for a 8 step answer!!!

Comment: @DrD 5 letters to full change, it takes too long to move into common words 8-step might actually be impossible especially because you have to move to the wrong vowel before getting to the right one (7 steps now) and 2 steps to reach vowel movement (9).

Comment: Point well taken @IT Alex.

Comment: Interesting. Did a small prog (using a dict of ~16000 5-letters words), and the best it can find is *exactly* your answer :-)

Comment: It's interesting how the ladder itself seems to contain some subtle political commentary

Comment: @e2-e4: Same here. I even added french, german, spanish and italian word lists, but couldn't find anything better than 9 steps.

Comment: @EricDuminil try to add the word `BIDEN` ...  ;-)

Comment: @e2-e4: I had to, because it isn't present in any word list I had.

Comment: @e2-e4 oh, so you allowed letters to be removed and added?

Comment: @e2-e4 sorry, I still don't get it. What would the complete chain look like? It doesn't seem to make sense to repeat any word.

Comment: @EricDuminil (removed previous comments to avoid the 'chat' punishment) there would be incorrect words in between in 5 steps if BIDEN is auth., and we can only change 1 letter at once, so indeed adding it wouldn't hurt (then dep on algo, the tree search (in mine) is a bit faster by stopping at 4 common chars)

Comment: @e2-e4: Once again, I don't get it. Getting into chat wouldn't bother me. 'BIDEN' must be in the graph, doesn't it? Do you have an example of the incorrect words? What would the chain look like, exactly?

Answer (score 18):

Here it is in 10 steps, at least

> TRUMP
>  TRAMP
>  TRAMS
>  TEAMS
>  BEAMS
>  BEATS
>  [BENTS](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bent) (*noun* -  stalks of stiff coarse grass)
>  [BINTS](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bint)
>  [BINES](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bine)
>  [BIDES](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bide)
>  BIDEN

Answer (score 14):

Here is a possible 9 step:

> TRUMP 
>  TRAMP 
>  TRAMS 
>  TEAMS 
>  TERMS 
>  TERES - a shoulder blade muscle 
>  BERES - bere: a type of cereal grass 
>  BEDES - bede: a devout deity petition 
>  BIDES 
>  BIDEN

Comment: That's 10 steps still

Comment: @AnthonyIngram-Westover Steps is counted from one to another, so 10 words is only 9 steps.

Comment: But is TERES in [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/teres) on its own? I'm not so sure...

Comment: Are bere and bede in Merriam-Webster?

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/beres not there

Comment: @DrD Oh sorry, I went off Scrabble words...

Answer (score 11):

If deletions and insertions are allowed, it is possible in 7 steps:

> TRUMP
>  RUMP
>  RUM
>  RIM
>  RID
>  RIDE
>  BIDE
>  BIDEN

Comment: But deletions and insertions aren't allowed.

Comment: @bobble I will leave that up to OP and mods. Some word ladders allow it and OP never specified.

Comment: Hello @Beefster. Thanks for your answer. Honestly when I made up the puzzle I did not even think of removing/adding letters. To me "change one letter at a time" meant replacing it with another. If that did not come across here I apologize. This is something new I learned today. For my next word ladder puzzle I will keep it in mind. Thanks again.

Comment: Another 7 using this format `TRUMP - RUMP - BUMP - BUM - BUD - BID - BIDE - BIDEN`

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution in only 8 intermediate steps:

> 0. [trump](https://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/trump)
>  1. [tramp](https://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/tramp)
>  2. [trams](https://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/trams)
>  3. [teams](https://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/teams)
>  4. [terms](https://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/terms)
>  5. [teres](https://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/teres)
>  6. [tires](https://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/tires)
>  7. [tides](https://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/tides)
>  8. [bides](https://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/bides)
>  Done: [biden](https://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/biden)

It is possible that shorter paths still exists, because I couldn't obtain the complete MW dataset.

---

#### Methodology:

1. First obtained a word list

   ```
   aspell -d en dump master | aspell -l en expand > words.en.txt
   ```
2. Keep only words that are 5 letters long

   ```
   awk 'length($0)== 5' wordlist1.txt > wordlist2.txt
   ```
3. Kepp only words without apostrophes (`'`)

   ```
   awk '!/'\''/' wordlist2.txt > wordlist3.txt
   ```
4. Remove words with capital letters (proper nouns)

   ```
   awk '!/[A-Z]/' wordlist3.txt > wordlist4.txt
   ```
5. Add 'biden' and 'teres' as words

   ```
   printf "%s\n" biden teres >> wordlist4.tx
   ```
6. Sort the file

   ```
   sort wordlist4.txt > words.sorted
   ```

After that a simple [Breadth first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) in ruby was enough to obtain the result, and finally the answer was confirmed to contain only words that exist in MW.

````
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# frozen_string_literal: true

words = File.readlines('words.sorted', chomp: true)

def distance_is_1?(letters, otherword)
  diff = 0
  val_letters = otherword.split('')

  0.upto(4) do |i|
    diff += 1 if letters[i] != val_letters[i]
    return false if diff > 1
  end
  diff == 1
end

def distance(letters, otherword)
  diff = 0
  val_letters = otherword.split('')

  0.upto(4) do |i|
    diff += 1 if letters[i] != val_letters[i]
  end
  diff
end

def neighbors(word_list, word)
  letters = word.split ''

  word_list.select do |w|
    dist = distance_is_1?(letters, w)
    dist
  end.map(&:downcase).uniq
end

solutions = { ['trump'] => distance(%w[b i d e n], 'trump') }

iter = 0
counted_nodes = {}

loop do
  res = {}
  new_counted = {}
  solutions.each do |s, _v|
    neighbors(words, s.last).uniq.each do |n|
      if s.include?(n) || counted_nodes.include?(n) || distance(%w[b i d e n], n) > 12 - iter
        next
      end

      new_counted[n] = s + [n]
      res[s + [n]] = 1
    end
  end
  solutions = res
  counted_nodes = counted_nodes.merge new_counted
  iter += 1
  break if iter > 12

  p 'solutions', solutions, solutions.count
  if solutions.any? { |k, _v| k.last == 'biden' }
    p('FINAL ANSWER', solutions.select { |k, _v| k.last == 'biden' })
    exit
  end
end
```
````

Comment: This is the same as the 9-step accepted answer, but it is nice that you added your working.

Comment: Thanks, it's almost the same because I didn't have the word `beres` in my list, I'm running it again with that word to see It there is anything shorter than that.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis: Actually now that I see it again, it isn't the same because that answer contains lists not in the dictionary specified by OP.

Comment: I think you're confusing [this answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/103878/37714) with [this answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/103882/37714). The second one is the exact same as yours. And this is 9 steps, not 8.

Comment: @LukasRotter: Oh right, I was wrong

Comment: I didn't try your code and don't know how long it takes, but it looks like at least O(n²). If you're interested, you could try an algorithm like this one in order to find the neighbours: https://pastebin.com/8q7fm6A7

You iterate once over every word, and you save them into a hash of arrays, each time replacing one letter by `'-'`.

You can then iterate over the values of the hash, and select the ones with more than one element: every word inside this array has a distance of exactly 1 with all the other ones.

Comment: For example: `{"-RUMP"=>["CRUMP", "ERUMP", "FRUMP", "GRUMP", "TRUMP"], "T-UMP"=>["THUMP", "TRUMP"], "TR-MP"=>["TRAMP", "TROMP", "TRUMP"], "TRU-P"=>["TRUMP"], "TRUM-"=>["TRUMP"]}`